# Wrap function passing NULL to lower-level haven::read_dta function in R

Tags: r

I am trying to build a function wrapping over `haven::read_dta()` similar to the `wrap_function()` defined in the code below.

My `wrap_function()` has a default `variables = NULL`, which should be able to pass `NULL` to  `haven::read_dta()`'s  `col_select`  argument if no values are specified. However, passing the `NULL` from `variables` to `col_select` throws an error (i.e. 'Error: Can't find any columns matching col_select in data.').

Can someone help me understand why this happens and how could I build a `wrap_function` capable of passing a `NULL` default value to the lower-level function?

Thanks!

```
library(reprex)
library(haven)

df_ <- data.frame(a = 1:5,
                  b = letters[1:5])

haven::write_dta(df_,
                 path = "file.dta")

# works well:
haven::read_dta(file = "file.dta",
                col_select = NULL)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>       a b    
#>   <dbl> <chr>
#> 1     1 a    
#> 2     2 b    
#> 3     3 c    
#> 4     4 d    
#> 5     5 e

# does not work:
wrap_function <- function(file, variables = NULL){
  
  haven::read_dta(file = file,
                  col_select = variables)
  
}

wrap_function("file.dta")
#> Note: Using an external vector in selections is ambiguous.
#> ℹ Use `all_of(variables)` instead of `variables` to silence this message.
#> ℹ See <https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-external-vector.html>.
#> This message is displayed once per session.
#> Error: Can't find any columns matching `col_select` in data.

sessioninfo::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
#>  os       CentOS Linux 8              
#>  system   x86_64, linux-gnu           
#>  ui       X11                         
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
#>  ctype    en_US.UTF-8            
#>  date     2021-05-14                  
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package     * version    date       lib source                       
#>  cli           2.4.0      2021-04-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)               
#>  crayon        1.4.1.9000 2021-04-16 [1] Github (r-lib/crayon@965d1dc)
#>  digest        0.6.27     2020-10-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)               
#>  ellipsis      0.3.1      2020-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)               
#>  evaluate      0.14       2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)               
#>  fansi         0.4.2      2021-01-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)               
#>  forcats       0.5.1      2021-01-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)               
#>  fs            1.5.0      2020-07-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)               
#>  glue          1.4.2      2020-08-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)               
#>  haven       * 2.3.1      2020-06-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: You just need to *embrace* the argument by wrapping it in double curly brackets`{{ }}`, previously called "curly-curly". This passes the variable properly. See the programming with dplyr [vignette](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#indirection-2) for more info.

```
wrap_function <- function(file, variables = NULL){
  
  haven::read_dta(file = file,
                  col_select = {{ variables }})
  
}

wrap_function("file.dta")
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>       a b    
#>   <dbl> <chr>
#> 1     1 a    
#> 2     2 b    
#> 3     3 c    
#> 4     4 d    
#> 5     5 e
```

---

Unfortunately it's a little hard to understand that this is necessary without looking at the code. If you look up the `haven` repository, you can see that `read_dta` [uses the double-curly](https://github.com/tidyverse/haven/blob/ed2ddda853a244dd3dedb5de552cf74e8440d388/R/haven-stata.R#L47) around `col_select` as well. This is a pretty good indication that you need to use it in your wrapper function.

If you look further, it is using them to pass the argument to a function `skip_cols`, which [uses it inside](https://github.com/tidyverse/haven/blob/ed2ddda853a244dd3dedb5de552cf74e8440d388/R/utils.R#L26) `tidyselect::vars_select`. The reason this is needed is so that you can *delay evaluation* of the argument until the point that you actually need it. In other words, it lets you call the function like this:

```
wrap_function("file.dta", variables = a)
```

instead of forcing you to do something like

```
wrap_function("file.dta", variables = "a")
```

and saves you a lot of typed quotes, especially with a lot of columns. You see this pattern in `dplyr` and other `tidyverse` functions a lot, especially any time an argument refers to a dataframe column rather than a variable.

In other words, you want to not have the code check exactly what `a` is until you reach `skip_cols`, which knows that `a` refers to a column inside the file you're reading. If you don't use the curly braces, it will think that `a` is some object in your working environment.